# I want to update a table in mysql after inserting a row into another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
bill
(id,amount,points)

bill_history
(id,bill_id,amount,points)
```

When a row is inserted into bill_history , i want to sum up the amount and points from the bill_history table and it should be updated in the bill table according to the bill_id

Comment: please help me with this. it could be done with firing two queries, but i want to learn how can it be done via triggers or may be functions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create one trigger [`AFTER INSERT`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php) on `bill_history` table.

And in this trigger you can wrote logic to update `SUM(AMOUNT)` AND `SUM(POINT)` in `bill` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ins_bill_history AFTER INSERT ON bill_history
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE bill 
            SET points = (SELECT SUM(points) FROM bill_history WHERE bill_history.bill_id = NEW.bill_id),
                amount = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM bill_history WHERE bill_history.bill_id = NEW.bill_id) 
        WHERE bill.id = NEW.bill_id;
    END;
|
```

Another solution would be to use a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) to `SUM` the `points` and `amount` on the fly:

```
CREATE VIEW v_bill AS 
    SELECT bill.*, SUM(bh.points) AS 'points', SUM(bh.amount) AS 'amount'
    FROM bill b INNER JOIN bill_history bh ON b.id = bh.bill_id 
    GROUP BY b.id
```

**Note:** In case of using the `VIEW` you have to remove the columns `points` and `amount` on table `bill`.

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 6

Comment: Your query have to start with `DELIMITER |`! A better solution would be to use the `VIEW` solution.

Comment: is it efficient if i fire two queries. After insert , if successful , update second table??

Comment: I would go with one on these solutions here (`TRIGGER` or `VIEW`). But you can `UPDATE` after `INSERT` too.

Comment: i did it through triggers.  it is working for me.  i simply created an sql update query with sub queries.  i was finding it difficult earlier but managed to make one.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way :

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(columns....)
   VALUES(..........)

SET v_lastinsertedrecord = LAST_INSERT_ID()

UPDATE YourTable SET (COLUMNS='value') WHERE id=@lastinsertedrecord
```